# No XML returned from DocuSign connect

Tags: docusignapi, ibm-bpm

I have set up DocuSign Connect to send message to the listener(setup on https port 9443) when document is completed. And it seems to be responding to the listener but without xml payload

The response looks like following:

Response: {"status":"200","data":{"serviceStatus":"end","key":"@1","step":"End","reset":false,"data":{},"actions":null}}

How can I get xml payload back from DocuSign?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect sends to the default ports of `443` for HTTPS: and `80` for HTTP. If you cannot use port 443 for Production contact DocuSign to review possible options. Also check success or failure logs in DocuSign Connect Configuration page to check for the issue.

Comment: Port is fine. As mentioned, I do get response from Docusign but the data is empty. The response looks like something shown above. The response shown is taken from logs. Also in logs, we have the envelope xml payload but just not included in response.

Comment: Above response does not look like DS Connect XML message, as it has status 200 and when posting message from DS to your listener DS will not post any status code. Can you try configuring a free https://www.webhookapp.com listener on DocuSign Connect to see that issue exists on your end?

Comment: I also have xml data in the log which look like this:
Envelope Data:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email></Email><UserName>manju</UserName><Delivered>2018-03-23T03:45:29.953</Delivered><Signed>2018-03-23T03:45:48.343</Signed><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Completed</Status>
Note: this is just part of what is in the log not full xml

Comment: It seems issue is on your side to receive an XML message, as I suggested can you configure a free webhook listener and see if that webhook is receiving the message. If yes then you need to check the infrastructure/code on your end to see why XML is not coming properly in your controller.

Comment: To read the xml properly, I am trying to build web service as mentioned in connect guide: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf
Would you be able to help me out in understanding what is the Docusign API web reference? What is Retrieving Service Endpoint URL?
Thanks

Comment: I am using following in web service:
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="https://demo.docusign.net/API/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl", mappedName="DocuSignConnectListener")
Getting an error: DocuSignEnvelopeInformation cannot be resolved to a type
Please help!

Comment: Try using `https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl` or `https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl`

Comment: Also which coding language you are using?